# How to copy a header with picture from one docx to an other docx

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I want to copy one header from a Word docx (opensml) to another Word docx.

I do it like this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546917.aspx

but the problem is that I have a picture in my header. Does anybody know how to get the pic copied too?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to copy the header's relationships part, and the binary image part itself.

If the rel id doesn't change, that's all you need to do.  If it does change, you'll need to update the relId in the picture XML in the header itself.

Comment: Assume you will need to change the relId because otherwise sometimes you will have a duplicate. This has to change in both document.xml and document.xml.rels

Comment: How to copy the releationships part?